# Передача базы данных в приложение

Tags: json, база-данных

есть готовая база данных sqlite на сервере (порядка 40000 строк), каким образом лучше всего передать все данные из нее в android приложение, в котором тоже лежит база данных отображающая эту? формировать огромный json?

Comment: а это делается один раз ?

Comment: @dobriy_zhuk, и каждый раз нужны все 40к строк? все они меняются?  
правильнее вести логи изменений и обмениваться только измененными записями. а первый раз можно и базу (дамп, json или в любом другом удобном виде) в asset'ах иметь.